# Why are items added to a list inside a for loop not showing up?

Tags: list, for-loop, dart

I am trying to add items to a list using a for loop like this:

```
double numPoints = 100;
List points = new List<LatLng>();
for(var i = 0 ; i == numPoints; i++ ) {
   points.add(LatLng(i.toDouble(),i.toDouble()));
}
```

However if I call `points` after this loop it returns an empty list. How can I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `i == numPoints` check. Since i starts at 0, `i == numPoints` evaluates to `false` and the loop is never executed. Replace it with `i <= numPoints` instead.

Comment: `i <=  numPoints` will generate a `List` with 101 points.  Presumably the goal is to have `points.length == numPoints`, in which case you'd want `i < numPoints`.